# Handle Cookie in between domain and sub-domain asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have 2 site ie `sub.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`.

When a user logs in into `mydomain.com` and if the credentials are of subdomain then the user should be logged in into sub application. To handle this,

1. when the user logs in into `mydomain.com` then a call is made to sub application and if the credentials are valid then session is set.
2. after that the main application calls the login URL of the sub application. It should automatically login and redirect to default page.

The session value in cookie is set for `.mydomain.com` and `.sub.mydomain.com`. I am setting the cookie for `sub.mydomain.com` but still it is setting cookie for `.sub.mydomain.com`. I am not sure if the issue is occurring due to this? But I am not able to login.

Also the Session which was set in the first request is null when the second request is triggered.

How can I set the Session object for the second request?